# Kotlin function to filter an arraylist and the cast it in object

Tags: android, kotlin

Hello I have an arraylist, and I have an object, is there a function to filter an arraylist and cast it in object?

example:

```
var array: ArrayList<User> = ArrayList()
array.add(User(123))
array.add(User(683))
array.add(User(329))

val user: User = array.filter{ it.code == 683}
```

**EDIT**

Found the solution:

```
var array: ArrayList<User> = ArrayList()
array.add(User(123))
array.add(User(683))
array.add(User(329))

val user: User = array.find{ it.code == 683}
```

Comment: Kotlin gives you a nicer way to create your list:

`val array = listOf(User(123), User(683), User(329))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find` / `firstOrNull` or `findLast` / `lastOrNull`, depending on the desired output:

```
val user: User? = array.find{ it.code == 123 }
```

Note that these functions returns a nullable type.